# Either computations in servant handler

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, servant

A [servant-server Handler](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.13/docs/Servant-Server.html#t:Handler) is a newtype wrapper over an `ExceptT`, and has instances for `MonadThrow`, `MonadCatch`, `MonadError`, etc.

This might be a somewhat contrived example, but it shows an issue I often face:

In a handler I want to call three functions that return `Either String Int`, then perform a computation of type `Int -> Int -> Int -> IO (Either SomeError Text)`, taking the three `Int`s from before.

How should I structure this code to ensure that an error is returned as early as possible?

I see that I can use `Either`'s `Monad` instance to “collapse” the first three `Either String Int` computations into e.g. `Either String (Int,Int,Int)`, and then binding the `IO` computation to some result value and then use `case` to decide whether to return a successful result or use `throwError` to throw the `SomeError` type (after a conversion?), but I was hoping to be able to something like the following:

```
f, g, h :: Either String Int
a :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO (Either SomeError Text) 

myHandler :: Handler Text
myHandler = do
    x1 <- f
    x2 <- g
    x3 <- h
    liftIO $ convertError $ (a x1 x2 x3)
```

Is it possible to write it similar to the code above?

Comment: You might have an issue in that `Handler` is an `ExceptT ServantErr`, but your errors are `String`s. Can we assume you have a function `String -> ServantErr` that you can use to convert the errors?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a function `strToServantErr :: String -> ServantErr` for converting the errors returned by `f,g,h` into errors that can be returned by your handler, then we can use:

- [`liftEither`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#v:liftEither) to get the `Either String Int`s into `ExceptT String`s.
- [`withExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#v:withExceptT) to convert from `ExceptT String` to `ExceptT ServantErr` as required by `Handler`.

```
x1 <- withExceptT strToServantErr $ liftEither f
```

As you're doing this three times, we can make it neater using [`mapM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:mapM):

```
[x1, x2, x3] <- mapM (withExceptT strToServantErr . liftEither) [f, g, h]
```

---

Now that we've sorted the arguments, we can use the same idea to fix the return. Renaming your `convertError` function to `someErrorToServantErr` for uniformity and assuming it has type `SomeError -> ServantErr`, then we can do:

```
result <- liftIO $ a x1 x2 x3
withExceptT someErrorToServantErr $ liftEither result
```

We unwrap the `IO` computation of `a`, then lift it to `ExceptT` and convert the exception type.

After tidying away some of the code into a helper function, this gives us something like:

```
myHandler :: Handler Text
myHandler = do
    [x1, x2, x3] <- mapM (liftMapE strToServantErr) [f, g, h]
    eitherResult <- liftIO $ a x1 x2 x3
    liftMapE someErrorToServantErr eitherResult
  where liftMapE f = withExceptT f . liftEither
```

Which will fail ASAP with a converted error as desired, and while it's dense is hopefully not all that unreadable.

---

You could also go the Applicative route, although I can't find a way of making it particularly nice (I've not used applicative functors much though, I'm probably missing some useful tricks):

```
myHandler :: Handler Text
myHandler = do
    let [x1, x2, x3] = map (liftMapE strToServantErr) [f, g, h] -- [Handler Int]
    tmp <- a <$> x1 <*> x2 <*> x3 -- IO (Either SomeError Text)
    eitherResult <- liftIO $ tmp
    liftMapE someErrorToServantErr eitherResult
  where liftMapE f = withExceptT f . liftEither
```

Any improvements on the above code are welcome!

Comment: You can go even further and use your custom error type in an ExceptT monad (or something similar) and use `hoistServer` (see [here](https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html#using-another-monad-for-your-handlers)).

Comment: @AlpMestanogullari Ooh, cool. I don't actually know anything about `servant`, so hopefully OP will see your comment and find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a Handler construction is missing in hnefatl's answer (assuming the question was asked about Servant 0.15 and around). Notice

```
newtype Handler a = Handler { runHandler' :: ExceptT ServantErr IO a }
```

this is what i had to do

```
eitherToHandler :: (e -> ServantErr) -> Either e a -> Handler a
eitherToHandler f = Handler . withExceptT f . liftEither
```